# jQuery noconflict new version while keeping old jQuery as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project that was so poorly designed that it's a basically a brick and mortar setup. Upgrading apparently was never so much as a passing thought.

For example, all the external scripts in this development are stored at the top of the body and moving them breaks everything due to how it was rolled out. So my dilemma is: a lot if this existing project is built on jQuery 1.4.4, but a lot of the planned new stuff is reliant on things in 1.7 and up. Unfortunately as it is, I need to load 1.4.4 in first, leaving it as the standard while loading in 1.8.3 and having 1.8.3 be the version with no conflict set. The problem is no matter how I try to load version 1.8.3 in, either before or after the 1.4.4, 1.8.3 ends up overriding 1.4.4 and causing either all out breakage or silent failures.

Is there anything I can do to load both and have 1.8.3 be my no conflict without breaking 1.4.4?

Comment: Have you attempted to just use 1.8.3 and remove 1.4.4?

Comment: I have attempted to remove 1.4.4 and leave only 1.8.3 and I get fatal breaks. I have tried 1.8.3, noConflict, 1.4.4, and get breaks, and I have tried 1.4.4, 1.8.3, noConflict, and everything fails silently. The code base is a horrible mess, if I had time to rewrite the break points I would but to much to do in less than enough time to do it

Comment: In all honesty I can't fathom why it breaks the way it does fatal or silent, other than the fact 1.8.3 is causing the conflict despite no conflict being setup. I have done similar things in the past, but on my own code base. The code here is originally I would assume someone who was familiar with a whole different language, not familiar with web development at all, and taking a first run crack at it, and having it actually work but in no way expandable, unfortunately this is a production piece of software, that needs a ground up rewrite but, thats not in the cards currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your jquery 1.4.4 is set to $, you can do something like this:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script> var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> var newJquery = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6BvNh/1/

Comment: All though this appears to work in your example, I am still getting far to many unexpected breaks. So I am gonna have to bank on the likely hood that my problems with this entire code base all though obvious otherwise. Stem way further down the line than I imagined, cause in all, all methods attempted should have worked just fine. But the case is that it isn't so for the purpose of this currently project within the project I am going to have to build some underhanded shady stuff, and then propose to the project heads a full rebuild ground up. Thanks

Comment: No need to do the extra `noConflict()` before loading the new script. After you load the new script do a `var $jq = Query.noConflict();` You can also try `Query.noConflict(true);` if you still getting clashing calls.